# How to open Specific View Controller from Share Extension click, Otherwise Store Data into my App Database

Tags: objective-c, ios-extensions, ios8-share-extension, share-extension

I Developed one Chat application in that, I have one ForwardViewController.I Want To Open ForwardViewController from ShareExtension click How can I do that if it is not possible then how can I Store that data into my database,
or Any other alternate way,
Thanks in Advance 
Example: - Forward image from gallery to direct WhatsApp contacts.